# Approximation of a generalized harmonic series

Tags: approximation

Take a sequence of positive integers $\{n_d\}_{d\in\Bbb N}$ and fix two positive real numbers $x$ and $y$.

Is there a way to estimate
$$
\sum_{d=1}^N\frac{n_d}{x+dy}
$$
in function of $x,y$ and $N$?

Comment: no. $\phantom{,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,}$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich. I think that there was in the past a shorter answer by Did. I cannot find it again. Cheers :-)